# Why after initializing the array I cannot assign some value in array?

Tags: java, arrays

This is my code, after initialized the array, I cannot able to reassign some value in array. It shows array index out of bound exception.

```
public class NewClass {
    public static void main(String args[]){

        String cl[]={};
        cl[0]="10";      
        System.out.print(cl.length);        
    }    
}
```

my output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at NewClass.main(NewClass.java:15)
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: your `cl` array size is `0` and you trying to insert value so `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` you can go for dynamic list such as `List<String> c1=new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: is possible to store array in list?

Answer (score 8):

```
String cl[]={};
```

Creates an instance of an empty array, so you can't add any elements to it.

In order to create a non empty array, use either

```
String cl[] = {"something",...};
```

or

```
String cl[] = new String[theArrayLength];
```

Comment: so what is the solution. ?

Comment: @Ram Use an [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), if you need the "array" to be extensible.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to declare your array, you can do something like this:

```
String cl[];
```

After that you can initialize your array by calling this:

```
cl = new String[10];
```

And your `System.out.print(cl.length);`  will return what you want.